# FCOM doesn't work in Turbo Assembler

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, compare

I have a problem with comparison in tasm. I have a code

```
cycle:
...some code...
fninit
fld limit
fld currentX    
fcom st(1)
jge exit
jmp cycle
```

But it jumps to exit mark even if conditions aren't met. I check it in turbo debugger and fpu stack values are right. How to fix it?

Comment: You want `fcomi` not `fcom` (assuming you have P6+) otherwise insert a `fstsw ax; lahf` because `fcom` only sets fpu flags not cpu. Also you should use `jae` not `jge` since `SF` and `OF` are zeroed (that's the reason for the unconditional jump) and only `ZF` and `CF` make sense.

Comment: I tried to use fcomi, but I got "Illegal instruction error" when run tasm.exe myTask.asm

Comment: Only works with P6+ you might need to enable that instruction set (`.686` directive or somesuch, tasm is ancient)

Comment: So, it it possible to do it with tasm? Sadly, I can use only tasm and dosbox.

Comment: Have you tried `.686` directive?

Comment: Can't set. Got "Illegal instruction"

Comment: Then use the workaround (which should be `sahf` not `lahf`, sorry)

Comment: Hate this tasm so much. But thanks for helping!

Comment: If you want to use FCOMI, Turbo Assembler didn't support it until version 5.3.

Comment: `sahf`, I have corrected it in another comment already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fcom` only sets fpu status bits, not the cpu flags so you can't directly use a conditional jump. There is an `fcomi` instruction which does, but that's only available when using a P6+ cpu and an assembler that understands such instructions. According to Michael Petch, for tasm you need at least version 5.3. A workaround is to transfer the fpu status bits to cpu flags using `fstsw ax` and `sahf`.

Also note that in either case, the relevant fpu status bits `C0`, `C2` and `C3` get transferred to `CF`, `PF` and `ZF` respectively, so you should use a conditional jump that checks these flags. In your case this means `jae`.

See also section *8.1.4 Branching and Conditional Moves on Condition Codes* in the *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture* and of course the instruction set reference as usual.